# Azure Compute Emulator Admin Priviledges - Registering WCF URL

Tags: wcf, azure, privileges, administrator

I am working on upgrading a project to Windows Azure 1.3 and I am running into an issue with hosting WCF services in an Internal Web Role. I get the following exception when trying to access the services:

```
HTTP could not register URL http://127.0.0.1:5111/service.svc/. Your process does not have access rights to this namespace
```

I did have a similar issue when working with Azure 1.0 and resolved it by with the following code:

```
new BasicHttpBinding() { HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact }
```

With this new issue, there seem to be a few common solutions; using the above code, runing the httpcfg tool to explictly change namespace reservation, and running as Administrator.

As far as I know, the httpcfg tool will not work for an Azure Internal WebRole because the port is dynamically assigned. Running Visual Studio as Administrator and debugging the Cloud project does not fix the problem either (Visual Studio does launch the Emulator).

It seems like the Azure Compute Emulator does not inherit the permissions from the Visual Studio process. Has anyone run into a similar problem, any ideas on fixes, work-arounds?

Karl

Comment: Did you add the following line to your csdef? 
<InputEndpoint name="HttpIn" protocol="http" port="5111" />

Comment: I did not add that code. I was under the impression that for internal endpoints you could not specify a static port. Has this changed for Azure 1.3?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, my suspisions were proved correct. When the Azure Compute Emeulator starts, it adds the Web Role instances in IIS, but the App Pool Identity does not have permissions to register namespaces.

I found this blog article which describes how to change the identity of the app pool when a Web Role instance is started.

http://www.wadewegner.com/2011/01/programmatically-changing-the-apppool-identity-in-a-windows-azure-web-role/

This is a less than ideal solution, but works.